# Definition of fasted state

Tags: medications

Is there a general definition what consists a fasted state? The medical literature I have read so far uses the term ambiguously, i.e. from overnight abstinence to 2h of no food intake. Is there a general accepted definition and can this state be objectively measured or is it measured by questionnaire / adherence to protocol?

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: What do you need the fastet patient for? For anaesthesia, usually at least 6h after a meal and 2h after fluid intake are required. For blood tests, in a hospital you usually do them early in the morning before breakfast (so ~8-12h after the last meal intake).

Comment: I'm studying the literature of EGCG toxicity of solid green tea extracts..a fasted state seems to be a risk factor for adverse effects..